# How to count By Quarter using aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

I am Using MongoDB. I have ordered item Collection in which each ordered item has been stored by Date(iso date). Now I want to retrieve count all the items By Quarter wise.

for Example when I will pass:-http://localhost:8080/demo?quarter=Q1 Then It will returns the total count of first Four Month(i.e, First Quarter)

How can I discover quarter of 4 months.I want to use Aggregation for it.
How can I Implement These using Aggregation in spring boot.

My Aggregation code:

```java
@Override
public List<Order> demoByQuarter(String quarter) {
   MatchOperation matchOperation1 = 
   Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("months").lte(3));
        MatchOperation matchOperation2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("months").gte(3));

        ConditionalOperators.Cond cond = ConditionalOperators.when(String.valueOf("Q1".equals(quarter)))
                .thenValueOf(String.valueOf(matchOperation1))
                .otherwiseValueOf(String.valueOf(matchOperation2));

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.match(where("date").ne(null)),
                Aggregation.project().and(month("$date")).as("months").and(cond).as("month"),
                Aggregation.group("month").count().as("count"),
                project("count").and("month").previousOperation());

        List<Demo> demo=  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "user",Demo.class).getMappedResults();
        System.out.println(orders.size());
        return demo;
}
```

when i run this code then i am getting data in following way:

```java
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "userId": null,
        "email": null,
        "productName": null,
        "date": null,
        "count": "9",
        "productId": null,
        "month": null,
        "year": null,
        "quantity": null,
        "quarter": null
    }
]
```

it returns total number of count of all month that are available yo database.
while My actual data that i wants to :

```java
[
    {
      
        "quarter": [
        "id": "in string",
        "userId": "userId",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "productName": ["p1","p2"],
        "count": "",// here it returns only count of first 4 month for Q1 quarter
        "productId": "productId",
        "quarter":"Q1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please show your source code and describe what are the results you expect and what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Spyros K i have updated my code.